# create dictionary from list same values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If i have a dictionary with lists with equal values:
`a = {'abc': [['aaa', '123'], ['aaa, '321']]}` how this values can be gathered to another dictionary like this: `a = {'abc': {'aaa':['123','321']}}` 
I tried

```
aa = {'abc': [['aaa', '123'], ['aaa', '321']]}

ab = {}
bb = []
for i in aa:
    for elem in aa[i]:
        path = elem[0]
        name = elem[1]
        bb.append(name)

ab[path] = []
ab[path] = (bb)

print ab
```

But i don't think it's right way.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Do the inner lists always have two values? If not, what happens if there are three, and one or two of those are equal? Also, does the order in the inner lists matter? What if the first value is different and the second is the same?

Comment: @tobias_k not always two, but i practice on two valued lists. If values are more than one, first values are always equal each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
def to_nested_dict(list_dict):
    d = {}                                   # initialize the outer dict
    for k, lst in list_dict.items():
        d[k] = {}                            # initialize inner dicts
        for x, y in lst:
            d[k].setdefault(x, []).append(y) # initialize and populate innermost list
    return d
```

This uses `setdefault` to provide a defalt value (an empty list) in case of a new key, but you can just as well use an `if`-statement or a `collections.defaultdict(list)` for this.

Example:

```
>>> to_nested_dict({'abc': [['aaa', '123'], ['aaa', '321']]})
{'abc': {'aaa': ['123', '321']}}
>>> to_nested_dict({'abc': [['aaa', '123'], ['aaa', '321'], ['bbb', '456']]})
{'abc': {'aaa': ['123', '321'], 'bbb': ['456']}}
>>> to_nested_dict({'abc': [['aaa', '123'], ['aaa', '321'], ['bbb', '456']], 'efg': [['eee', '789']]})
{'abc': {'aaa': ['123', '321'], 'bbb': ['456']}, 'efg': {'eee': ['789']}}
```

Not that this assumes that the inner-most lists will always have two elements, a key and a value, and that the key can be the same in different lists, but can also differ, resulting in more than one entry in the created dictionaries.

Comment: Wait, I thought it was supposed to work for arbitrary length lists (where you have `lst` here) based on your comments with OP. Better to do `for elem in lst: d[k].setdefault(elem[0], []).extend(elem[1:])` or something then?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Yes, that's one way to handle this case, but I'm not sure whether it's the right way, or whether that's an issue at all. I'll wait until OP elaborates on that case, how the result should look then.

Comment: I think that's fair. I'm not entirely sure I've understood the OP either.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one line solution for you:

```
ab  = { k:{v[0][0]:[ x[1] for x in v ] } for k,v in aa.iteritems() }
```

Output:

```
print ab
{'abc': {'aaa': ['123', '321']}}
```

Voilà

Comment: Hm, but this will only work if the first value in the inner lists is the same for _all_ the lists. Not sure whether it's really meant this way, but maybe I overcomplicated things...

Comment: @tobias_k Actually they are the same, this is what he replied to you in an earlier comment, quoting him :"If values are more than one, first values are always equal each other"